# headers.set doesn't set the Authorization header

Tags: ionic3, angular5

Below is the snippet of code taken from [this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-role-based-authentication-with-passport-in-ionic-2-part-2/) but since I'm using Angular 5, I changed `headers.append` to `headers.set`.

However, I will still receive `401 Unauthorized` error which basically says that I'm unable to authorize my login using JWT. I tried sending the received token using POSTMAN and setting Authorization header without any problem, but my server will always reject my code below.

```
getTodos(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.set('Authorization', this.authService.token);

      this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/todos', {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(data => {
          console.log("ok getTodos");
          resolve(data);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("NO getTodos");
          console.log("err",err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: does your server allow authorization headers to be set in the first place? your server most likely is configured wrong from what i can see. Or you are sending an invalid token.

Comment: the code is wrong - with Postman it works as expected from what it is mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Immutable set of Http headers, with lazy parsing.` https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders

try this

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

The `.set` will return the `HttpHeaders`
`httpOptions.headers =
  httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'my-new-auth-token');`

In your snippet the result from `.set` call is not stored anywhere.

Edit: If you need further assistance or explanation what is immutable let me know. Useful URL https://angular.io/guide/http#update-headers - it's always good to check the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks. But wow, it seems there're so many breaking changes when angular version changes. Tutorials on the net that as recent as last year can be considered obsolete already.

Comment: better check the official docs :) reading articles or tutorials are only good to get some ideas of how to do it - but sometimes the code is deprecated or in bad quality for the sake of simplicity of the examples

Comment: you can also put a tag to angular5 - since it's specific to that version